# Update a textView in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

When i try to update the value of a Textview after a dialogfragment i **get the right value** but if the previous value is longer its **old view is still visible** (and ugly) in the background.

I tried calling **onResume()** for the current fragment but no improvements.

I just call a dialog and when the listener **onFinishEditDialog()** is called i just set the text

If i open another app and i come back it is perfect (the old is gone)
how is this possible?

in the xml layout:

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txttotalcho"
                    style="@style/importantTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="40dp"
                    android:text="33 cho"
                    android:textSize="64dp" />
```

in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onGoToPage(int pageNumber,boolean verso, Pasto p,ArrayList<CiboSelezionato> cibiSelezionati,String extra) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment firstDetail = 

(Fragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(SECOND_DETAIL_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.remove(firstDetail);

                ft.commit();
                        FragmentTransaction ft2 = fm.beginTransaction();
        switch (pageNumber){

                        case Constants.P_SCELTA_PASTO:{
                             WizardPasti10 secondDetail = WizardPasti10.getInstance(this);
        ft2.replace(R.id.anchor_layout,secondDetail,SECOND_DETAIL_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                            break;
                        }
                        case Constants.P_TOTAL_CHO:{
                             WizardPastiTotalCho secondDetail = WizardPastiTotalCho.getInstance(this);
     ft2.replace(R.id.anchor_layout,secondDetail,SECOND_DETAIL_FRAGMENT_TAG);

                            break;
                        }
             ft2.commit();
                    View v1,v2;
                    v1=(View)findViewById(R.id.anchor_left);
                    v2=(View)findViewById(R.id.anchor_layout);
                    v1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                v2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
```

in the fragment WizardPastiTotalCho:

```
private TextView txtTotalCho;
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View firstView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizardpastitotalcho, container, false);
                txtTotalCho = (TextView)firstView.findViewById(R.id.txttotalcho);
            txtTotalCho.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View button) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    DialogFragment newFragment = new TastierinoDialogFragment(WizardPastiTotalCho.this,Constants.CARBOIDRATI,0);
                    newFragment.show(ft, "totalchoDialog");
                }
            });
    }



     @Override
            public void onFinishEditDialog(int dialogType, String inputText) {
     //called when i close the dialogFragment
                txtTotalCho.setText(inputText+" cho");
txtTotalCho.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//just to see the difference
                try {
                    totalCho=Float.parseFloat(inputText);
                    tmpPasto.setCarboidrati(totalCho);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();    
                }
            }
```

[image: overlapping label]

Comment: Are you sure this is the same TextView you are using, not another one (for instance from a second dialog instance)? By the way when you post your complete code regarding your problem, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Are you sure you're changing the same Fragment and not accidentally stacking them in the same container?

Comment: @DeeV if i slide to another application and come back i see it perfectly clean

Comment: @Minsky i attached the code, i think i'm always working on the same txtTotalCho can it be some sort of refresh problem?

Comment: @Mark That's still implying that you're just adding new Fragments of the same class on top of each other in the same container. When you leave and come back, the others are gone and you add a new one with the last value. Thus you only see the that one.

Comment: @DeeV wouldn't that call onCreateView(), onAttach() or getInstance()?
[i have logs messages in these functions, they don't appear]

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would.  Another reason could be for some reason you have multiple TextViews on top of each other as @Minsky suggested.  Try setting it multiple times in a row with slightly decreasing size each time to verify if that's what's happening. You might see a bunch of views on top of each other.

Comment: @DeeV if i repeat many times i always have in the background ONLY the first, (ex. is 888888 i update to 55555 then if i write 1 i see some 888s in the background) but if i switch to another application and come back it's perfect (the background is white and i see only the new updated value)

Comment: @Mark, thx for the code. But I am sorry, that I can't see the problem. Can you provide the full code listing? Especially your calling activity and your xml-layout-files, pls?

Comment: @Minsky of course, thanks to you for the help. I call the fragment with a "replace" in the main

Comment: @Mark, I am sorry. I tried to reproduce your project with the code snippets you provided, but there are too much missing to get anything to work. My last advice is, that you backup your project and remove anyhting you don't need to reproduce the issue and then start debugging work from there. Your Code shows that there are at least 3 different fragment(dialogs) plus their layouts in the project. It is not visible to me whether all are involved in this issue or not. Good luck.